# preg_match end by a specific symbol

Tags: regex

This is a string

```
$string = "example.com/TARGET/noneed/noneed/noooo";
```

how to get TARGET using preg_match to start finding from first "/" till second "/" and ignore whatever follows

yup, its a bit nooby question, sorry but im not really good with regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
"#/(.*?)/#"
```

This finds the first `/` then matches the [least possible](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) until it finds the second `/`.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/iqryK)

Comment: Better performance solution would be regex without lazy operator: `#/([^/]*)#` (http://ideone.com/DNPK4)